# QueryDSL Build error AnnotationProcessor ' ' not found Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, querydsl

Hallo everyone i have one litle problem with my bulid.gradle i will run my project but this ist not possible. Does someone have an idea why this can be ?
I get this error:

Execution failed for task ':compileQuerydsl'.
> Annotation processor '' not found

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Hier is my bulid.gradle config

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
        queryDslVersion = '4.2.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.10"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.5.Final'

    // QueryDSL
    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:${queryDslVersion}"
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
    compileOnly "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    /* TEST */
    // Querydsl
    testCompile "com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:${queryDslVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:general")

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'liquibase'
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Check out https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/108 Add to your build.gradle: compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}

Answer (score 1):

i have found this problem. That's right:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'
        queryDslVersion = "4.2.1"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.9"
        classpath('net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.18')
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    //Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    //Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.5.Final'

    // QueryDSL
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")

    //Joda time
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

    //SpringBoot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
}

apply plugin: 'liquibase'
apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'
def queryDslSourceDirectory = 'src/querydsl/java/generated'

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = queryDslSourceDirectory
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir queryDslSourceDirectory
        }
    }
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}
```